# Javascript: Add Class/ID to only that parent div when clicked

Tags: javascript

Suppose I had:

```html
<div class="a">
<div class="b">
<div class="c"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="a">
<div class="b">
<div class="c"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I click the div with class `c` I only want to print that parent `div` of class `a`. But I don't want to print the other parent div of class `a`.

I thought the best way to do this was if you click class `c` you then add `a` class to that parent class `a` and then I can target that `div` within my print style sheet.

How would I do this, so it only add a class to that parent class `a` and not to the other same named `div`s?

Comment: You simply go up the DOM tree from the clicked node, for example using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 0):

You can select the closest element parent of an element by [using the closest method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.c').forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.a').forEach(div => {
      div.classList.remove('clicked');
    });
    div.closest('.a').classList.add('clicked')
  });
})
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.a {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.b {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.clicked {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}

.c {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```